# How do I get Windows 2008 R2 to update total memory in displays?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virsh

I am trying to get a feeling for how much memory I need for my Windows 2008 R2 server by changing the memory while the server is running.  While this works well the indicators in the Windows Task Manager and Resource Manager are really inconnsistent and confusing.

The graphs of the memory usage are accurate, but the numeric printouts of the memory are not.

For example (using resource monitor, but they are all off):  At 1280M (the amount I started the server with) the system is running at 314 M (in use) so 24.5%.  When I decrease the ram to 768M it says that my in used memory is 826M with 64% used physical memory.  The host system is reporting a little more than 840M for the process which is impossible (826M / .64).

I believe everything to be working except the totatl RAM which would account for all the oddities.  Since I hope to be swapping back and forth for testing and just using the graphs is a little too rough for me is there a way to get the system to update the total memory in the displays?

Comment: To be clear - are we talking about hot-swapping RAM here, as in you're physically plugging in hardware while the OS is running?

Comment: @RyanRies I doubt he is hotswapping. He mentions host system so the server is a VM with a hypervisor that allows on the fly memory adjustments. I never tried something like this myself on Windows, but (based upon what I know of the theory of dynamic RAM adjustments and my experience with Aix and Solaris) I would guess that after such a change it can take a while before things settle and the hypervisor and the guest agree on what is going on.

Comment: It is a virtio function part of kvm(qemu/libvirt).  The change is instant.  It is just that windows refuses to acknowledge that the max ram has changed.  I believe Server 2012 does the dynamic ram properly(?).  I am using virtio balloon for the ram change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Server 2008 R2 are you using? Hot-Add memory is only supported in Enterprise onwards.